# How do I solve $x^4-3x^2+2=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve $x^4-3x^2+2=0$ ?

I would appreciate some kind of hint here.  I have no clue how to start this problem.

Comment: Hint: Let $z = x^2$ and rewrite as an equation in $z$.

Comment: Let $y = x^2$ (and so $x^4 = y^2$) and see if that helps,

Comment: Try to consider $t=x^2$ and solve it for $t \geq 0$.

Comment: Try considering $\unicode[Geramond]{1071}=x^2$. (Kidding, of course)

Comment: hint 1: $x$ is a number. hint 2: $x^2$ is a number too. hint 3: $x^4$ is the square of the latter number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x^2=t$

Then equation becomes $t^2-3t+2=0\Rightarrow(t-1)(t-2)=0\Rightarrow t=1 $ or $t=2$
$\Rightarrow x^2=1,2\Rightarrow x=\pm1,\pm \sqrt2$

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $u = x^2$ and the equation becomes $u^2 - 3u + 2$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the product $(y-2)(y-1)$ for which the expansion is $y^2 - 3 y +2$. Now let $y = x^2$ to obtain $x^4 - 3 x^2 + 2 = (x^2 -2)(x^2 -1) = 0$. This leads to $x^2 = 2$ or $x^2 =1$. These two equations yields $x \in \{ - 1, 1, - \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  Thanks for the hints.  Here is what I did.

Let $u=x^2$.

$x^4-3x^2+2 = u^2-3u+2 = (u-2)(u-1)=0$. Solve for u I get

$u=2,u=1$ but $u=x^2=2$, so $x=\pm \sqrt 2$ and $x=\pm \sqrt 1$

Answer (score 0):

We can complete squares as follows:
\begin{align*}
x^4-3x^2+2&=0\\
x^4-3x^2&=-2\\
x^4-3x^2+\color{green}{\frac{9}{4}}&=-2+\color{green}{\frac{9}{4}}\\
\left(x^2-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2&=\frac{1}{4}\\
\left(x^2-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}&=0\\
\end{align*}
Now we can factor this difference of squares:
\begin{align*}
\left(x^2-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}&=0\\
\left(x^2-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x^2-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)&=0\\
\left(x^2-1\right)\left(x^2-2\right)&=0\\
(x+1)(x-1)\left(x+\sqrt{2}\right)\left(x-\sqrt{2}\right)&=0\\
\end{align*}
Hence, the solutions are $\pm 1$ and $\pm\sqrt{2}$.